# How to get a sharedPreferences key value before attachBaseContext called?

Tags: android, localization, sharedpreferences, android-context

My aim is overriding application language before it creates context and i'll use that context for calling other activities. Its possible via colling "recreate()" method on "onCreate" but i dont want to recreate activity to achive that goal. E.g

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {

    //null exception here
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    String langKey = getString(R.string.pref_language_key);
    String langValue = sharedPreferences.getString(langKey, null);

    super.attachBaseContext(ConfigurationUtil.wrapLanguage(newBase, langValue));
}
```

If this is not possible, any ideas how to set application language that user have choosen from settings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(newBase);
```

please use newBase context and not your Activity context